# How to give variable size images as input in keras

Tags: image-processing, machine-learning, neural-network, deep-learning, keras

I am writing a code for image classification for two classes using keras with tensorflow backend. My images are stored in folder in computer and i want to give these images as input to my keras model. `load_img` takes only one input image so i have to use either `flow(x,y)` or `flow_from_directory(directory)`, but in `flow(x,y)` we need to also provide labels which is length task so i am using `flow_from_directory(directory)`. My images are of variable sizes like 20*40, 55*43..... but [here](https://keras.io/preprocessing/image/) it is mentioned that fixed target_size is required. In [this](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/issues/1920) solution it is given that we can give variable size images as input to convolution layer using `input_shape=(1, None, None)` or input_shape=(None,None,3) (channel last and color images) but  fchollet mention that it is not useful for flatten layer and my model consist both convolution and flatten layers. In that post only moi90 suggest that try different batches but every batch should have images with same size, but it is not possible me to group images with same sizes because my data is very scatter. So i decided to go with `batch size=1` and write following code:

```
from __future__ import print_function
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense, Dropout, Flatten, Conv2D, MaxPooling2D
from keras import backend as K
import numpy as np
from keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator

input_shape = (None,None,3)

model = Sequential()
model.add(Conv2D(8, kernel_size=(3, 3),
                 activation='relu',
                 input_shape=input_shape))
model.get_weights()
model.add(Conv2D(16, (3, 3), activation='relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))
model.add(Dropout(0.25))
model.add(Flatten())
model.add(Dense(32, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dropout(0.5))
model.add(Dense(2, activation='softmax'))

model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy',optimizer='rmsprop',metrics=['accuracy'])

train_datagen = ImageDataGenerator()
test_datagen = ImageDataGenerator()
train_generator = train_datagen.flow_from_directory('/data/train', target_size=input_shape, batch_size=1,class_mode='binary') 
validation_generator = test_datagen.flow_from_directory('/data/test',target_size=input_shape,batch_size=1,class_mode='binary')
model.fit_generator(train_generator,steps_per_epoch=1,epochs=2,validation_data=validation_generator,validation_steps=1)
```

Now i am getting following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-8-4e22d22e4bd7>", line 23, in <module>
    model.add(Flatten())

  File "/home/nd/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/keras/models.py", line 489, in add
    output_tensor = layer(self.outputs[0])

  File "/home/nd/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/keras/engine/topology.py", line 622, in __call__
    output_shape = self.compute_output_shape(input_shape)

  File "/home/nd/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/keras/layers/core.py", line 478, in compute_output_shape
    '(got ' + str(input_shape[1:]) + '. '

ValueError: The shape of the input to "Flatten" is not fully defined (got (None, None, 16). Make sure to pass a complete "input_shape" or "batch_input_shape" argument to the first layer in your model.
```

I am sure it is not because of `img_dim_ordering` and `backend` but because of [this](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/issues/3850) i have checked both are `th` Please help to correct he code or help how i can give variable size images as input to my model.

Comment: Waiting for more correct answers

Answer (score 7):

You can train variable sizes, as long as you don't try to put variable sizes in a numpy array.

But some layers do not support variable sizes, and `Flatten` is one of them. It's impossible to train models containing Flatten layers with variable sizes.

You can try, though, to replace the Flatten layer with either a `GlobalMaxPooling2D` or a `GlobalAveragePooling2D` layer. But these layers may condense too much information into a small data, so it might be necessary to add more convolutions with more channels before them.

You must make sure that your generator will produce batches containing images of the same size, though. The generator will fail when trying to put two or more images with different sizes in the same numpy array.

Comment: Thnx for your reply Daniel. I will make group of same size images, but how to proceed with that? What changes i have to make in my abobe mention code.

Comment: When i replace `model.add(Flatten())` with `model.add(GlobalMaxPooling2D())` i am getting following error: `File "/home/nd/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/keras/utils/data_utils.py", line 557, in get
    six.raise_from(StopIteration(e), e)

  File "<string>", line 2, in raise_from

StopIteration: 'NoneType' object cannot be interpreted as an integer`

Comment: I believe that somewhere before this layer your net is outputting (or even getting as input) `nan` values. It's possible that the `relu` activation is causing this by accidentally getting all results equal to 0 (and thus not having a gradient). You may try (if your images are made only of positive values) to pass initializers to the layers with relu, making all weights start as positive.

Comment: My all images made only of positive values. I add `kernel_initializer='glorot_uniform'` to two Conv2d layes present above to `GlobalAveragePooling2D ` layer in my code but getting same error.

Comment: Try replacing 'relu' by another, such as 'tanh', just in case.... so we can make sure this is not the issue.

Comment: replaced relu by tanh, facing same problem. For information i have two classes with each have 130 images (total=260) and for test total 11. is softmax or batch selection is creating problem. In below comment i am sending again full code.

Comment: ooh, i am unable to send full code, characters allowed are limited.

Comment: Waiting for your valuable reply

Comment: In that case I don't know what the problem is.... not sure if this is important, but usually, 'softmax' is made for 'categorical_crossentropy', while 'sigmoid' is for 'binary_crossentropy'. --- If you have alwayw only one true class, it's ok to use 'softmax'. If you may have both classes true, or both classes false, then it should be 'sigmoid'.

Answer (score 5):

See the answer in https://github.com/keras-team/keras/issues/1920
Yo you should change the input to be:

```
input = Input(shape=(None, None,3))
```

The in the end add **GlobalAveragePooling2D()**:

Try something like that ...

```
input = Input(shape=(None, None,3))

model = Sequential()
model.add(Conv2D(8, kernel_size=(3, 3),
                 activation='relu',
                 input_shape=(None, None,3)))  #Look on the shape
model.add(Conv2D(16, (3, 3), activation='relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))
model.add(Dropout(0.25))
# IMPORTANT !
model add(GlobalAveragePooling2D())
# IMPORTANT !
model.add(Flatten())
model.add(Dense(32, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dropout(0.5))
model.add(Dense(2, activation='softmax'))

model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy',optimizer='rmsprop',metrics=['accuracy'])
```

Answer (score 4):

Unfortunately you can't train a neural network with various size images as it is. You have to resize all images to a given size. Fortunately you don't have to do this in your hard drive, permanently by keras does this for you on hte fly.

Inside your flow_from_directory you should define a target_size like this:

```
train_generator = train_datagen.flow_from_directory(
    'data/train',
    target_size=(150, 150), #every image will be resized to (150,150) before fed to neural network
    batch_size=32,
    class_mode='binary')
```

Also, if you do so, you can have whatever batch size you want.

Comment: Ok. if i group same dimension images then is it possible? what changes i have to made in my code.

Comment: `target_size`, however, transforms the image by stretching/shrinking, rather than cropping, I believe.

Comment: This is not true