# Call model.fit in Keras for inputs of different shapes?

Tags: python, numpy, tensorflow, keras

I created a CNN whith Python and Keras which compresses 2D input of various length into a single output. All images have a height of 80 pixels, but different lenght, e.g. shape (80, lenght_of_image_i, 2), where 2 is the number of color channels.

I have 5000 images, the shape of the training data array X in numpy is (5000, 1) and the array has dtype object. This is because storing content with different shape is not possible in a single numpy array. Each object in the list has shape (80, lenght_of_image_i, 2).

With this said, when I call the model.fit(X,y) function of the sequential model, I get the following error:

```
    ValueError: Error when checking input: expected conv2d_1_input to have 4 
    dimensions, but got array with shape (5000, 1)
```

Converting the numpy array to Python list of numpy arrays also doesn't work:

```
    AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'ndim'
```

Zero padding or transformations of my data to get all of my images to the same shape is not an option.

**My Question now is:** How can I call the model.fit(X,y) function when my data has not a fixed shape?

Thank you in advance!

**Edit:** Note that I do not have a problem with the architecture of my network (since I am not using dense layers). My problem is that I cannot call the fit function, due to problems with the shape of the numpy array.
My model is a replicate of this network: http://machine-listening.eecs.qmul.ac.uk/wp-content/uploads/sites/26/2017/01/sparrow.pdf

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to give variable size images as input in keras](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47795697/how-to-give-variable-size-images-as-input-in-keras)

Comment: As stated - resizing the image is not an option. I also do not have a problem with dense layers since my model architecture has none, to handle images of different size.

Comment: Yes, but as stated by Daniel Möller in his [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47795697/how-to-give-variable-size-images-as-input-in-keras), you can train on variable sizes as long as you're not trying to give them together. I thus don't think you can use `model.fit(X,y)` as it is. Maybe you could consider building mini-batches from images of similar shape yourself instead.

Comment: @Aldream, thanks for the advice, I'll try that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to pass "numpy arrays" to fit, of type "float". That is the only possibility.

So, you will probably have to group batches of images with the same length, or train each sample individually:

```
for image, output in zip(images,outputs):
    model.train_on_batch(image.reshape((1,80,-1,2), outputs.reshape((1,)+outputs.shape, ....)
```

Comment: Thanks, this is the solution I was looking for!