# How to give different size images to cnn model in keras/tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, spp

i confused to how to input two size pictures and it also can't use resize and crop.I have seen this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47795697/how-to-give-variable-size-images-as-input-in-keras?rq=1#) but it is also not resolved.this is my code but i get follow error:

StopIteration: 'NoneType' object cannot be interpreted as an integer

i hope you can give me some advice

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(Conv2D(filters=6,kernel_size=(5,5),padding='same',input_shape=(None,None,3)))
model.add(Activation('tanh'))  
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2,2))) 

model.add(Conv2D(filters=16,kernel_size=(5,5),padding='same'))  
model.add(Activation('tanh')) 
model.add(GlobalAveragePooling2D())
model.add(Dense(1))  
model.add(Activation('sigmoid'))
#sgd = optimizers.RMSprop(lr=0.01, clipvalue=0.5)
model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy',#'binary_crossentropy'categorical_crossentropy,
              optimizer='sgd',
              metrics=['accuracy'],
              )
train_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1./255,
                                   vertical_flip=True,
                                   horizontal_flip=True)

test_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1./255)

train_generator = train_datagen.flow_from_directory(
        train_data_dir,
        target_size=(img_width, img_height),
        batch_size=batch_size,
        class_mode='binary')#'binary'categorical)

validation_generator = test_datagen.flow_from_directory(
        validation_data_dir,
        target_size=(img_width, img_height),
        batch_size=batch_size,
        class_mode='binary')#'binary')

early_stopping = EarlyStopping(monitor='val_acc',patience=10,mode='max')
model.fit_generator(train_generator,
                    steps_per_epoch=nb_train_samples//batch_size,
                    epochs=nb_epoch,
                    validation_data=validation_generator,
                    validation_steps=nb_validation_samples,
                    callbacks=[early_stopping,
                               TensorBoard(log_dir='C:\\Users\\ccri\\Desktop\\new\\iou30\\426\\lenet\\log', write_images=True),
                               ModelCheckpoint(filepath='C:\\Users\\ccri\\Desktop\\new\\iou30\\426\\lenet\\canshu\\weights.{epoch:02d}-{val_loss:.2f}.h5', 
                               monitor='val_acc',                                   
                               save_best_only=True,
                               mode='auto')]
)
```

Comment: please format your error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only limitation is creating a numpy array that can fit images of different sizes.

You can solve this using either `batch_size=1` (then your numpy arrays will never be incompatible).

Or you can try to manually group all images of the same size in an array, train this array as a big batch, then do the same for other sizes.

Comment: Thank you daniel.but can you tell me how can i save error classification image in evaluate_generator or error image's name？

Answer (score -2):

I'm afraid that is not possible. How would the weight matrix be updated?

Suppose you initialize it to `2x2` matrix:

```
a b
c d
```

Once you trained on some `2x2` images, suppose, you would then want to train on `4x4` images. What would it look like? Where would the elements `a`, `b`, `c` and `d` go? Top-left? Middle? Top-right? Would you generate a new one? That would discard all the training progress up until now.

I would really suggest rescaling all images to common width and height. If that is not possible and you have relatively high amount of examples from each width and height you could simply create several neural networks (N1, N2, ...), and, theoretically, once you get to a layer which has the same shape independent of the input image switch to a shared neural network N_shared. However, you would need a lot of examples from each category.