# Wrong label shape with ImageDataGenerator

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, deep-learning

I'm trying to train a model with different dimensions of images, and usually I would use flatten, but flatten() expects a fixed dimensions for all images, which I have not.

Here I'm trying to replace flatten by GlobalMaxPool2D() but at the end I have an issue with the dimensions expected. I'm a new-learner to TensorFlow, and I have difficulties understand where I can tune my model to avoid having this issue in the shape expected ?

The code : (some imports are uncessary but it will be used further down, I added them in case of putative incompatibilities)

```
from __future__ import print_function
import keras

from keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense, Dropout, Activation, Flatten
from keras.layers import Conv2D, MaxPooling2D, GlobalMaxPool2D
import os
from random import shuffle

train_image_generator = ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1./255) # Generator for our training data
validation_image_generator = ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1./255) # Generator for our validation data
batch_size = 128

train_data_gen = train_image_generator.flow_from_directory(batch_size=batch_size,
                                                           directory=f"/kaggle/working",
                                                           shuffle=True,
                                                           class_mode='binary')
val_data_gen = validation_image_generator.flow_from_directory(batch_size=batch_size,
                                                           directory=f"/kaggle/working/",
                                                           shuffle=True,
                                                           class_mode='binary')

model = Sequential()
model.add(Conv2D(32, (3, 3), padding='same', input_shape=(None,None,3))) #We change the input shape because the images have different shapes but always 3 chan.
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(Conv2D(32, (3, 3)))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))
model.add(Dropout(0.25))

# model.add(Flatten()) #as all the pictures have different size, flatten does not work. Possibly other solutions found there :
model.add(GlobalMaxPool2D())
# https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47795697/how-to-give-variable-size-images-as-input-in-keras
model.add(Dense(512))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(Dropout(0.5))
model.add(Dense(num_classes))
model.add(Activation('softmax'))

# initiate RMSprop optimizer
opt = keras.optimizers.rmsprop(lr=0.0001, decay=1e-6)

# Let's train the model using RMSprop
model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy',
              optimizer=opt,
              metrics=['accuracy'])

# X_train_i = X_train_i.astype('float32')
# X_test_i = X_test_i.astype('float32')
X_train_i /= 255
X_test_i /= 255
model.summary()
model.fit_generator(train_data_gen,
        steps_per_epoch=2000,
        epochs=10,
        validation_data=val_data_gen,
        validation_steps=800)
#             batch_size=batch_size,
#             epochs=epochs,
#             validation_data=(X_test_i, y_test),
#             shuffle=True)


# Score trained model.
scores = model.evaluate(X_test_i, y_test, verbose=1)
print('Test loss:', scores[0])
print('Test accuracy:', scores[1])
```

The model sum up is the following :

```
Model: "sequential_11"
_________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
conv2d_20 (Conv2D)           (None, None, None, 32)    896       
_________________________________________________________________
activation_38 (Activation)   (None, None, None, 32)    0         
_________________________________________________________________
conv2d_21 (Conv2D)           (None, None, None, 32)    9248      
_________________________________________________________________
activation_39 (Activation)   (None, None, None, 32)    0         
_________________________________________________________________
dropout_20 (Dropout)         (None, None, None, 32)    0         
_________________________________________________________________
global_max_pooling2d_9 (Glob (None, 32)                0         
_________________________________________________________________
dense_19 (Dense)             (None, 512)               16896     
_________________________________________________________________
activation_40 (Activation)   (None, 512)               0         
_________________________________________________________________
dropout_21 (Dropout)         (None, 512)               0         
_________________________________________________________________
dense_20 (Dense)             (None, 2)                 1026      
_________________________________________________________________
activation_41 (Activation)   (None, 2)                 0         
=================================================================
Total params: 28,066
Trainable params: 28,066
Non-trainable params: 0
_________________________________________________________________
Epoch 1/10
```

The error is the following :

```
ValueError: Error when checking target: expected activation_41 to have shape (2,) but got array with shape (1,)
```

It definitely seems that the value is "halved" but I tried to remove some layers, I can't make it work.

Beside, if you can recommend a tutorial to understand those concepts better, I'm all ears.

Thank you very much ++

Comment: What is the shape of the array that holds the class labels ? There might be a mismatch between the shape of your output and the class label array. It can be that because you do a binary classification, you have the class labels array in the shape of (nx1) while your network expects an array of (nx2)

Comment: Hi Koralp, thanks for your answer. Actually I have no "labels" per se as the ImageDataGenerator.flow_from_directory is doing the work (as far as I understand it) by looking for images in different folders. Here I just have 2 images spread like 1 image in 2 different folders (ISUP1 and ISUP2 are the name). At the end of image generator I have the following :

Found 2 images belonging to 2 classes.

Comment: Well yes, the ImageDataGenerator indeed iteratively feeds the data to the model. However, if you check here https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/preprocessing/image/ImageDataGenerator#flow_from_directory You can see that using class_mode as `binary` will yield 1D binary labels, which can cause the dimensionality mismatch

Comment: Ah ! awesome ! it works ! If I wanted to use in ImageDataGenerator a binary classification, I should then have used a number of classes = 1 then. Thanks a lot ++

Answer (score 2):

I don't think you should have put `n_classes=1` (as your comment says) because it isn't `True`, and will probably bring confusion. You can use an approach that will work in all cases.

Using `class_mode='categorical'` will work in all cases, no matter what the number of classes is.

Then, in your final layers, you don't even have to set the number of categories manually, you can do this:

```
Dense(units=len(train_data_gen.class_indices))
```

Then you will always have a match between final neurons and number of categories. Then, always make sure you have a loss function that allows one-hot encoded output and you're good to go (e.g., `categorical_crossentropy`)

Comment: Thanks a lot, it's more reliable indeed